# Is $a$ invertible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We have that $R$ is a ring.

Suppose that $Ra=R$ and $bR=R$, for $a,b\in R$. Then we have that there is $x\in R$ such that $ab=1$ and $bx=1$.

Does it follow that $a$ is invertible?

Answer (score 4):

From $Ra=R$ you can conclude $ya=1$ for some $y$, and from $bR=R$ you can conclude $bx=1$ for some $x$.

This does not imply anything about $ba$ or $ab$, so what you wrote does not stand.

But let's suppose you meant to also say $ab=1$ in your hypotheses. Then that,  together with $ya=1$ does imply that $a$ is a unit (and $b$ too is a unit.)

Answer (score 3):

If $R$ is commutative then $ab=1$ alone gives you that $a$ is invertible.

Without supposing that $R$ is commutative the answer is yes too: multiply the first equation by $x$ and get $abx=x$. As $bx=1$ this implies $a=x$. You then get $ab=1$ and $ba=1$ so $a$ is invertible.